# Galois group of $f$ is cyclic if $\deg f$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Hello I am learning Galois Theory by myself and got lost in the following exercise:

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, and suppose that the splitting field of $f$ is generated by a single root of $f$.

a) Show that the Galois group of $f$ is cyclic if $n$ is prime, and that it is either cyclic or a Klein 4-group, if $n = 4$.

b) Let $K$ be any Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree $n$. Show that there exists an irreducible polynomial
$f$ of degree $n$ having $K$ as its splitting field, and that $K$ can be generated by a single root of this
polynomial.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

a) *Hint:*  The order of the Galois group of a polynomial is the same as the degree of its splitting field. Furthermore, any group  of prime order is cyclic. A group of order $4$ is abelian, and is either cyclic or isomorphic to Klein's Vierergruppe.

b) *Hint:* Think of the Theorem of the Primitive element.

Comment: However, the order of the Galois group (equivalently the degree of splitting field of $f$) itself might not be prime. For example, it may happen that $\mathrm{Gal} (f) \simeq S _{p} $. In fact, the Galois group of any irreducible polynomial of prime degree $p$ with all but two roots in $\mathbb{R}$, is isomorphic to $S_p$.

Comment: @penseur_32 the splitting field of $f$ is generated by a single root of $f$ so has degree $\deg f$, by assumption.